# Rendering a mesh in image viewport

Tags: opengl, shaders, rendering, frustum, frustum-culling

I have a mesh made of nearly half to a one million vertices. I also have some 6-DoF camera poses around this mesh. At these poses I'd like to find out which of the 3D points of this mesh get projected inside the image viewport of size 640x480. Basically I'd like to get the indices of the 3D points that fall inside this image window at a given pose. What is the best way to do it? Are there any shader functions or OpenGL functions that can allow me to do this quickly?

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is Frustum Culling. The problem is this doesn't work too well on individual vertices, because a vertex may be required for a face that is inside the frustum even if the vertex itself isn't. It would be too slow to do that every frame anyway.

If neither the mesh or cameras move, or they move predictably so you can precalculate everything, you can probably do the culling per-face. But then I'm not sure why you wouldn't just make renders of the thing in some 3D modelling software.

So if you really need culling in real-time, I recommend splitting the mesh into multiple parts that can be culled individually.

Other than that, [this link](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/) can get you started, and Google should help with the rest, now that you know what it's called.